# Apache 2.2 Weblogic Plugin for Mac

Tags: apache, weblogic, load-balancing, weblogic11g

Afternoon.
Does anyone know, is there mod_wl_22.so for OS X support? I've tried to use mod_wl22.so that is used for Linux, but it failed.
Have anyone configured Apache2.2 as a load balancer for Weblogic 11g?

Comment: Relevant (but doesn't help since there is no answer): https://community.oracle.com/thread/2560360 Unfortunately I'm not sure it can be done... but would be happy to see someone answer

Comment: It seems that there is no possibilities to use mod_wl22.so on OS X. The only way is to use mod_proxy, it does not have the smart fail-over capabilities that the weblogic plug-in has, but better than nothing. And obviously it is just a bad workaround for some cases.